# Deadly force allowed during a forcible felony in Florida?

Tags: criminal-law, florida, self-defense

You are at a stop light and see a person with a firearm run up to the car in front of you. They attempt to open the door and see a struggle begin as the door opens. You are absolutely sure this is a car jacking in progress. You happen to have your legal firearm with you. Are you allowed to use deadly force in order to stop the assailant?

Comment: Your motor vehicle is also a "lethal weapon" if used to stop such a crime. You are authorized to use it as "deadly force" as described in @ohwilleke's answer below to prevent a forcible felony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You are allowed to use deadly force in defense of another in this situation. The following sections of the Florida Statutes authorize the use of deadly force in this situation:

> 776.012 Use or threatened use of force in defense of person.—
>
> (1) A person is justified in using or threatening to use force, except
>   deadly force, against another when and to the extent that the person
>   reasonably believes that such conduct is necessary to defend himself
>   or herself or another against the other’s imminent use of unlawful
>   force. A person who uses or threatens to use force in accordance with
>   this subsection does not have a duty to retreat before using or
>   threatening to use such force.
>
> (2) **A person is justified in using or threatening to use deadly force
>   if he or she reasonably believes that using or threatening to use such
>   force is necessary** to prevent imminent death or great bodily harm to
>   himself or herself or another or **to prevent the imminent commission of
>   a forcible felony.** A person who uses or threatens to use deadly force
>   in accordance with this subsection does not have a duty to retreat and
>   has the right to stand his or her ground if the person using or
>   threatening to use the deadly force is not engaged in a criminal
>   activity and is in a place where he or she has a right to be.

A forcible felony is defined as follows:

> 776.08 Forcible felony.
>
> “Forcible felony” means treason; murder; manslaughter; sexual battery;
>   **carjacking**; home-invasion robbery; **robbery**; burglary; arson;
>   kidnapping; aggravated assault; aggravated battery; aggravated
>   stalking; aircraft piracy; unlawful throwing, placing, or discharging
>   of a destructive device or bomb; and any other felony which involves
>   the use or threat of physical force or violence against any
>   individual.